# What are the drawback of Hibernate

Tags: hibernate

Can someone elaborate the drawback of Hibernate framework,if any? My second question is which ORM tools is best suitable in terms of Performance and easy to implement?

Comment: The answer of this question is depending on so many factors.

Comment: The biggest drawback to Hibernate, and to any ORM tool for what is worh, is the **Object-Relational Impedance Mismatch**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Advantages:**

1. Hibernate supports Inheritance, Associations, Collections
2. In hibernate if we save the derived class object,  then its base
   class object will also be stored into the database, it means
   hibernate supporting inheritance
3. Hibernate supports relationships like One-To-Many,One-To-One,
   Many-To-Many-to-Many, Many-To-One
4. This will also supports collections like List,Set,Map (Only new
   collections)
5. In jdbc all exceptions are checked exceptions, so we must write code
   in try, catch and throws, but in hibernate we only have Un-checked
   exceptions, so no need to write try, catch, or no need to write
   throws.  Actually in hibernate we have the translator which converts
   checked to Un-checked
6. Hibernate has capability to generate primary keys automatically
   while we are storing the records into database
7. **Hibernate has its own query language, i.e hibernate query language
   which is database independent**
8. **So if we change the database, then also our application will works
   as HQL is database independent**
9. HQL contains database independent commands
10. While we are inserting any record, if we don’t have any particular
     table in the database, JDBC will rises an error like “View not
     exist”, and throws exception, but in case of hibernate, if it not
     found any table in the database this will create the table for us
11. **Hibernate supports caching mechanism by this, the number of round
     trips between an application and the database will be reduced, by
     using this caching technique an application performance will be
     increased automatically.**
12. Hibernate supports annotations, apart from XML
13. Hibernate provided Dialect classes, so we no need to write sql
     queries in hibernate, instead we use the methods provided by that
     API.
14. Getting pagination in hibernate is quite simple.

**Disadvantages :**

I don’t think there are disadvantages in hibernate.
Some may say hibernate is little slower than pure JDBC, actually the reason being hibernate used to generate many SQL statements in run time, but i guess this is not the disadvantage. Its need to be decide accoding to web project.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but not clear with disadvantages.